# Proving $\lim_{n\to0} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} x^{1/n} \sin x dx = 1$

Tags: limits, analysis, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve this question:

Prove that

$$\lim_{n\to0} \int_{0}^{\pi/2} x^{1/n} \sin x dx = 1$$

I know that both of $x^{1/n}$ and $\sin x$ are strictly increasing functions.

Than, all I need is just to showing this sequence has upper bound 1, however I can't.

In this case what should I do first?

Comment: Well as $n\rightarrow\infty$, $x^{\frac{1}{n}}\rightarrow{1}$ so I guess you're really just evaluating $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0\sin{x}dx$ which is equal to $1$

Comment: Do you know about the monotone convergence theorem or the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: You can use dominated convergence theorem to justify what @Quippy said

Comment: oh, thank you all!